# Javascript if statement is not working correctly

Tags: javascript, slider, counter

```
  //this counts how many images exist
  var img_count = $("#gallery_scroller img").length;
  //this is a number where I want the clicks to stop working
  var limit_count = img_count/3;

  var click_count = 1;

  if ( limit_count > click_count){

    $("#down_arrow").click(function(){
      click_count++
      var css_position = -1*click_count*300;
      $('#gallery_scroller img').css('top', css_position);
      alert(css_position+' '+limit_count+' '+click_count);
    });
  };
```

I put the alert at the end so I can observe the values everytime I click. It just keeps on going even though the click_count is larger than the limit_count. In the if condition, when I replace click_count with an actual number that is larger than the limit_count it works.

Comment: Add semicolon after `click_count++`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `if` statement isn't in the code in the `click` event handler. Once the handler is attached, only the code *within* the handler will get run when the click occurs.

I'm not entirely sure what your desired result is, but this is probably closer:

```
//this counts how many images exist
var img_count = $("#gallery_scroller img").length;
//this is a number where I want the clicks to stop working
var limit_count = img_count/3;

var click_count = 1;

$("#down_arrow").click(function(){
    if ( limit_count > click_count){
        click_count++;
        var css_position = -1*click_count*300;
        $('#gallery_scroller img').css('top', css_position);
        alert(css_position+' '+limit_count+' '+click_count);
    }
});
```

E.g., put the test *within* the event handler code.

---

Side note: There's no need for a semicolon at the end of the curly braces on an `if` block, e.g.:

```
    if (...) {
    };
//   ^--- no semi here
```

Side note 2: I've added a semicolon after `click_count++`. Without it, you're relying on the horror that is [automatic semicolon insertion](http://es5.github.com/#x7.9). You were okay because there was a line break after it, but in general, best to learn the rules of where semicolons go and always include them where they're required.

Answer (score 0):

your condition needs to be inside the event handler:

```
var click_count = 1;

$("#down_arrow").click(function(){
  if ( click_count < limit_count ){
    click_count++;
    var css_position = -1*click_count*300;
    $('#gallery_scroller img').css('top', css_position);
    alert(css_position+' '+limit_count+' '+click_count);
  };
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#down_arrow").click(function(){
 if ( limit_count > click_count){
    click_count++
    var css_position = -1*click_count*300;
    $('#gallery_scroller img').css('top', css_position);
    alert(css_position+' '+limit_count+' '+click_count);
  };
});
```